# unable to parse json property

Tags: json, api

I'm trying to get the value of username and id from the following output.

```
{
  "listusersresponse": {
    "count": 1,
    "user": [
      {
        "id": "f01e8ea4-2da5-11e4-a846-726c7bbb864f",
        "username": "admin",
        "firstname": "admin",
        "lastname": "test",
        "created": "2014-08-26T20:52:24-0400",
        "state": "enabled",
        "account": "admin",
        "accounttype": 1,
        "domainid": "c091153a-2da5-11e4-a846-726c7bbb864f",
        "accountid": "f01e7c02-2da5-11e4-a846-726c7bbb864f",
        "iscallerchilddomain": false,
        "isdefault": true
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

This is what I have tried

```
$url = file_get_contents("http://URL/client/&response=json");

$data = json_decode($url);

var_dump($data);

foreach ($data as $value) {
  echo $value->count;
  }
```

For this works and I get 1

However when trying to access "username"

```
foreach ($data as $value) {
  echo $value->user->username;
  }
```

I get the following error: Notice: *Trying to get property of non-object in "filename"*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

User is an array.

```
foreach ($data as $value) {
    echo $value->user[0]->username;
}
```

Not sure how your json looks with several users, It must be like this then I guess:

```
foreach ($data as $value) {
    foreach ($value->user as $user) {
        echo $user->username;
    }
}
```